# How can I add a condition inside a php object?

Tags: php

I have n php object like this:

```
        $test
        ->key1(1)
        ->key2(1)
        ->key3(1);
```

Is it possible to add a condition inside it?

like this:

```
   $test
   if(true) ->key1(1)
   ->key2(1)
   if(true) ->key3(1);
```

Comment: Why don't you just do this                       if ( $test ->key1(1) ->key2(1) ->key3(1))   do something;

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046629/conditional-builder-method-chaining-fluent-interface and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1189979/implementing-conditional-in-a-fluent-interface.

Comment: What do you want to check inside this condition?

Answer (score -1):

what you want is

```
if (condition) {
    code to be executed if this condition is true;
} elseif (condition) {
    code to be executed if this condition is true;
} else {
    code to be executed if all conditions are false;
}
```

for example

```
if ($YOUR_KEY == "key1") {
    //if key1 then do something
} elseif ($YOUR_KEY == "key2") {
    //if key2 then do something
} else {
    //if none condition work than do something else
}
```

here `$YOUR_KEY` is your variable and `"key1"` is your value

check [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_if_else.asp) and [http://php.net/manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) for reference

Comment: A switch statement is much better and cleaner ;)